# Python - String conversion to list

Tags: python

I have a string field : `"[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]"`. I want to convert this string to a list of strings.

For now I have the following function :

```
def stringToList(string):
    string = string[1:len(string)-1]
    try:
        if len(string) != 0: 
            tempList = string.split(", ")
            newList = list(map(lambda x: str(x), tempList))
        else:
            newList = []
    except:
        newList = [-9999]

    return(newList)
```

I want to know if there is a simpler or a shorter method with the same results.
I could use `ast.literal_eval()` if my input data were of type `int`. But in my case, it does not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worth to know:

```
import re

string = "[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]"
founds = re.findall('[\-A-Za-z]+', string)
```

It will find all that consist at least one of of `-`, `A-Z`, and `a-z`.

One pros is that it can work with less-neat strings like:

```
string2 = " [  Paris, Marseille  , Pays-Bas  ] "
string3 = "   [ Paris  ,  Marseille  ,   Pays-Bas  ] "
```

Comment: this is my favorite option but OP must somehow be certain of what can appear between the commas. For example as this answer now stands `"[Paris1, M4rseill3]"` would not work. It might therefore not be a bad idea to add a `\d` to the mix.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You're right. Additionally, I personally believe char-by-char processing is the most proper approach for this kind of parsing problem, which is exactly what `re` internally does. Stripping left and right sides, splitting, and conditionally selecting elements are can be simply done in code-level, however, internally it is a bit painful... I think...

Answer (score 3):

This splits it into a list of strings:

```
'[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]'.strip('[]').split(', ')                                                                                                                               
# ['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Pays-Bas']
```

Comment: Isn't this what i did?

Comment: Yes, it looks like we both did at about the same time

Answer (score 2):

Just use slicing and `str.split`:

```
>>> s = '[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]'
>>> s[1:-1].split(', ')
['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Pays-Bas']
>>>
```

Or `str.strip` with `str.split`:

```
>>> s = '[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]'
>>> s.strip('[]').split(', ')
['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Pays-Bas']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
s = "[Paris, Marseille, Pays-Bas]"

s = [i.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(' ','') for i in 
s.split(',')]
print(s)
```

output:

```
['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Pays-Bas']
```